# Is this a good way to encapsulate a derived class?

Tags: java, class

I have the following class:

```
public class Base{

    private static class Derived extends Base{ }
    private static class SuperDerived extends Base{ }

    public static Base createDerived(){ return new Derived(); }
    public static Base createSuperDerived(){ return new SuperDerived(); }
}
```

I don't want those derived classes be used outside of the Base class body directly.

Is that a good way to do that? I'm not sure about that thing because those derived may consist of 100 lines of code that will probably make the Base class hard to understand.

Comment: If you *don't want those derived classes be used outside of the* `Base` *class*, this is the right way to go

Comment: At least this reduces potential coupling by using one parent class instead of three. Examples of this pattern can be found in Effective Java by Josh Bloch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe but often not.

My main concern is that your design is driven by fear ("someone *might* abuse"). This can lead to all kinds of problems. There is a thing like too much encapsulation, especially when you have complex code which is bound to have "I could use that with a small change" bugs on the consumer side.

Often, it's enough to label a class as internal and not protect it very much. What's the point of protecting something that no one cares about?

I also advise against using `static` factory methods. It will cause all kind of pains when you have to write unit tests.

Your other concern is class size. If you still feel the pressure to protect the code, make the classes package private:

```
/*package*/ class Derived extends Base { ... }
```

The comment has no effect but documenting the intention (so no one thinks "oh, there is a `public` missing").

That way, only classes in the same package can access them.

Comment: Exactly what i was going to write. No static methods, no unnecessarily strict protection. Unless you are developing platform like Eclipse.

Comment: But for a factory method like `public Base createDerived(){ ... }` we have to create the instance of Base first. Doesn't that cause some kind of pain when we want to create the instance of derived? We should create the instance of Base class which I was going to make abstract and only then we will be able create the desirable instance.

Comment: @St.Antario do not put factory methods to base class, use separate factory class for that. Sources of spring-core library contain lots and lost of example of *right* API architecture.

Comment: @St.Antario: Move the factory method into a new class `BaseFactory`. Don't keep it in `Base`.

Answer (score 2):

If those classes are large I would advise to put `Base` and the `Derived` classes in a separate package and putting the `Derived` classes in separate files and making them package private. That would result in better readability of the code.

That is assuming you are not too worried about malicious developers creating that package themsevles to access the `Derived` classes.

Comment: You mean delcare them as just class `Derived extends Base{ }`, don't you?

Comment: @St.Antario yes, exactly

Answer (score 2):

Well, why don't you make your derived class classifier-less?

```
class Derrived extends Base {
}
```

The class without `public` or any classifier is accessible only from inside its package. So you can't extends it like `protected`. It will work only in `Derrived` class package.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them to be accessible outside `Base`, making them nested classes is pretty much your only option.

My personal preference is for nested classes to come at the end of the outer class, meaning they don't clutter your outer class, making it more readable.

Comment: I was not sure if I should move those classes into a specific package and declare them with the default access modifier. Maybe that would be better here?

Comment: You can do that, but it doesn't stop any other class in that package from using them. Depends on how critical your requirement of non-access to the subclasses is.

Comment: Of course we cannot prevent the user from putting their classes into the packege, but I think nobody on Earth will put their classes into the package with a very  specific name. Is it reliable?

Comment: Reliable insofar as you cross your fingers and hope. It really depends upon how worthwhile it would be to get direct access to your classes. If they contain the keys to the kingdom... Not reliable. If they contain some very specific utility method only useful to `Bass`... Sure, why not.